True if X consecutive numbers in a cell
I'm using Excel 365 and would like to stipulate whether it is true or not that the text cell I'm looking at has x amount of consecutive numbers. 
For this example, I would like to know when there is 5 consecutive numbers in the cell:




Text cell
True?




AB 131
FALSE


50353 GO
TRUE


A A 6
FALSE


CV90356
TRUE


TT 2041
FALSE


13190 13224
TRUE




As you can see it will return TRUE if five consective numbers appear in the cell, even if there are two lots of this sequence in the cell. What formula could I use to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Try: =OR(LEN(TEXTSPLIT(A2,TEXTSPLIT(A2,SEQUENCE(10)-1,,1),,1))=5)

You could try using the following formula:


=MAP(A2:A7,LAMBDA(x,OR(LEN(TEXTSPLIT(x,TEXTSPLIT(x,SEQUENCE(10)-1,,1),,1))=5)))


Or, as commented above:
=OR(LEN(TEXTSPLIT(A2,TEXTSPLIT(A2,SEQUENCE(10)-1,,1),,1))=5)


Or,
=OR(LEN(IFERROR(--MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),5),0))=5)



Or if you are able to use regex:
=REGEXTEST(A2,"\d{5}")



What comes to mind when looking at this answer is whether it spills. It does i.e. =REGEXTEST(A2:A7,"\d{5}").

Exact Number of Consecutive Digits

In my opinion, the requirement here is to return TRUE for each cell that contains any number of occurrences of isolated 5 consecutive digits i.e. not more, not less.
Of course, it is not clear due to the simplistic sample data.

In B2:
=REGEXTEST(A2:A21,"(^|\D)\d{5}($|\D)")

In D2:
=REGEXTEST(A2:A21,"(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)")


The above two formulas could be wrapped inside an IFERROR() to hide errors.

In I2:
=LET(data,A2:A21,digits,5,
    ds,TEXT(SEQUENCE(10)-1,"@"),
    MAP(data,LAMBDA(m,LET(
        l,LEN(m),
        s,MID(m,SEQUENCE(LEN(m)),1),
        sc,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(l),LAMBDA(rr,r,
            IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(INDEX(s,r),ds)),
                IF(r=l,IF(digits-rr=1,-1,0),
                    IF(rr=-1,1,rr+1)),IF(rr=digits,-1,0)))),
    ISNUMBER(XMATCH(-1,sc))))))


More of the Same (Already Posted)

This covers an occurrence of at least 5 consecutive digits, not less but equal or more.

In H2:
=LET(data,A2:A21,digits,5,
    ds,TEXT(SEQUENCE(10)-1,"@"),
    MAP(data,LAMBDA(m,LET(
        s,MID(m,SEQUENCE(LEN(m)),1),
        sc,SCAN(0,s,LAMBDA(rr,r,
            IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(r,ds)),rr+1,0))),
    ISNUMBER(XMATCH(digits,sc))))))


The remaining columns in the screenshot above cover the results of the other posts so far which are mostly the same as produced by the formula above.

